# Animate div position in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider, jquery-animate

I’m learning to use jQuery, I’m not an expert programmer. I’m using `animate` effect to build a horizontal navigation for the loop of WP installation (no scrolls). I animate 960px in *x* axis the loop with a “Next Page” button and go to start going (to 0px *x* position) with a “start” button. The container of this has an `overflow:hidden` CSS property in order to hide the posts outside the container.

Please see a [live example](http://webpro123.com/tests/).

I don’t know how to stop the slide effect when reaching the end of the loop div. Maybe with a conditional statement, but I don’t know to approach this.

This is the script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".left-slide").click(function(){
  $("#slide-container").animate({
    left:"-=960"
  }, 1500 );
});
$(".right-slide").click(function(){
  $("#slide-container").animate({
    left:"0"
  }, 1500 );
});
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Would something like this work?

```
if($("#slide-container").css('left') > -($("#slide-container").width()))
{
}
```